# Expo bare-minimum workflow installation issue

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to create a bare-minimum workflow for the first time and I am getting an issue

My commands

```
expo init --template bare-minimum abcd
```

Then i select managed or advanced ( issue is with both )

Then I fill the app.json details and then it asks me to use Yarn to install dependencies

It does not matter whether I select Yarn or not

Then I get this error message

```
404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bare-minimum - Not found
```

any help around this will be appreciated

Please Note :- My expo version is 2.10.1
My NPM version is 6.5.0
My node version is 11.9.0

Answer (score 0):

upgrading expo worked..

Thanks guys for looking into my question